# Google Docs Slow on Firefox

Tags: windows-7, firefox, internet

When editing Google Docs in Firefox, it is slow to the point that the cursor does not keep up with what i'm typing.

Troubleshooting:

- In Safe Mode, Google Docs works fine.
- In regular mode, disabling all
  addons has no effect.
- In regular mode, resetting all preferences to
  default has no effect.

Any ideas as to what the culprit could be?

Comment: Firefox Safe Mode? Or Windows Safe Mode?

Comment: Off-topic: it's been always slow for me in Firefox. Even in Pale Moon /Waterfox. The only solution so far is to use Chromium/Chrome/SRWare Iron.

Comment: @iglvzx, Firefox Safe Mode.

Comment: If it's not add-ons, could it be a plug-in (Flash maybe?). It can also be 2D rendering acceleration (with poor graphics drivers). Some stupid anti-virus software also try to intercept every HTTP request, delay it by several hundred milliseconds and finally gave up and pass it to the browser. It could also be the error logging/debugging facility.

Comment: @billc.cn Thanks for the troubleshooting tips. I don't think it's drivers, because that would affect safe mode too (same with AV). And the plugins are also enabled in safe mode, so it can't be those.

Comment: To be honest I've never found Google Docs to be particularly speedy in any browser. You're not using a netbook perchance? I have a similar issue with any web app when using my Asus EEEPC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it runs fast in Safe Mode, it's probably background software or services that are interfering, you'll need to determine which.

Perhaps use MSConfig to temporarily disable various services/software at startup until you find the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Latest Firefox 12 works fine with Google docs. You can get it **[here](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/)**.

Google Chrome works fine with Google services. You can get latest one **[here](https://www.google.com/chrome)**

Also check that you have enough free RAM space. Try to terminate all possible apps / processes before working with FF.

Hope this helps.